# Schedule job in laravel time interval

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have three schedule job every hour in Kernel.php like below:

```
$schedule->command('get:twitter')->cron('* 1 * * * *');
$schedule->command('get:facebook')->cron('* 1 * * * *');
$schedule->command('get:googleplus')->cron('* 1 * * * *');
```

I want to run this three schedule in some time interval like below:

```
$schedule->command('get:twitter')->cron('* 1 * * * *');//after 1 hour
$schedule->command('get:facebook')->cron('30 1 * * * *');//after 1.30 hour
$schedule->command('get:googleplus')->cron('45 1 * * * *');//after 1.45 hour
```

Is this possible in laravel 5.1

Comment: Do you need to run them every hour or once a day?

Comment: they already run every hour ... but i want to make time interval like : first schedule run in every 1 hour , 2nd run in every 1.5 hour, 3rd run in every 1.45 hour ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no anything out of box but you can do something like this:

```
// every hour
$schedule->command('get:twitter')->hourly();

// every one and a half hours
$schedule->command('get:facebook')->cron('0 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * * * *');
$schedule->command('get:facebook')->cron('30 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * * *');

// every two hours at x.15 minutes (0.15, 2.15, 4.15 etc)
$schedule->command('get:googleplus')->cron('15 */2 * * * *');
```

Comment: I think everything will work here. You can create `every 1.45`, but it will be really long and ugly code. )

Comment: ok thank you very much .. now i will add this in my kernel.php

Comment: hi,
my client expectations are.

Run job every day at 11PM but on sunday it should run EVERY HOUR?

how can i do that?

please help

Answer (score 0):

With recent Laravel updates, you can run it as below:

```
// Run the task every hour at 17 minutes past the hour
$schedule->command('emails:send')->hourly(17);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options